# Customize the compiled filename in Rails 3.1 assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm using the asset pipeline in Rails 3.2.1

My app can having different CSS themes depending on users preferences. but 90% of the stylesheet is the same.

I'd like to have all my CSS compiled in a single file, but with the resulting filename depending on the user's name.

In Rails 2.x I could do this :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main.css', "themes/#{@user.css_theme}.css", :cache => @user.name %>
```

and the file would have the correct file name.

Now, with Rails 3.1+ I can use ERB to customize the required stylesheets, but if I set this in my layout :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

the compiled file is named application.css and I can't find a way to set a custom name.

Answer (score 1):

You just need define 2 lines in your head :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "themes/#{@user.css_theme}.css" %>
```

And in your application.css you have only the common part.

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to have only 1 file ;-)

Comment: I think you need do a lot of application_#{@user.css_theme} in your app/assets/stylesheet require all you want

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done, but I'm not happy about that for many non obvious reasons (and not easy to explain).